# Can't delete default route on linux

Tags: linux, routing

I have two default routes and I want to delete one of them, but can't.  I get no error message and the route is still there.  Am I doing it wrong?  Is NetworkManager screwing with me?

```
[11:09:52]user@host:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts$ ip route
default via 10.12.32.1 dev em1  proto static  metric 100
default via X.X.X.X dev em2  proto static  metric 101
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.12.32.1 dev em1
10.12.32.0/24 dev em1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.12.32.4
10.12.32.0/24 dev em1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.12.32.4  metric 100
X.X.X.X/29 dev em2  proto kernel  scope link  src X.X.X.X  metric 100

[11:15:31]user@host:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts$ sudo ip route delete default via 10.12.32.1 dev em1  proto static  metric 100

[11:15:41]user@host:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts$ ip route
default via 10.12.32.1 dev em1  proto static  metric 100
default via X.X.X.X dev em2  proto static  metric 101
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.12.32.1 dev em1
10.12.32.0/24 dev em1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.12.32.4
10.12.32.0/24 dev em1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.12.32.4  metric 100
X.X.X.X/29 dev em2  proto kernel  scope link  src X.X.X.X  metric 100
```

Since I can't take down `em1` during production hours, I tried a workaround:
I changed the metric on `em2` to 99 in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em2`.  But after ifdown `em2` and `ifup em2`, it still has a metric of 101.

EDIT:
Contents of ifcfg-em1:

```
# Generated by dracut initrd
NAME="em1"
DEVICE="em1"
ONBOOT=yes
NETBOOT=yes
UUID="8c695eab-d7ff-4b7c-960d-333788fbaf72"
IPV6INIT=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
TYPE=Ethernet
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
```

Contents of ifcfg-em2:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=1cc7a636-b9b0-4602-806a-81486188efb0
METRIC=99
NAME="em2"
DEVICE="em2"
ONBOOT=yes
NETBOOT=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPADDR=X.X.X.X
PREFIX=29
GATEWAY=X.X.X.X
DNS1=10.12.32.44
HWADDR=00:21:9b:99:2f:44
METRIC=99
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant `ifcfg` files? In the mean time you should be able to just [delete the one you don't want](https://dpaste.de/tLj2). It's possible NM is messing with you but you might be able to just disable it and use regular networking until you get the actual problem fixed.

Comment: @Bratchley Yes, I should be able to delete the one I don't want, but I can't... which is why I posted this question.

Comment: What's the error it gives you when you try something similar to the what's in my paste?

Comment: @Bratchley:  No error, see my original post at the top... it's all there.

Comment: This really does seem like NetworkManager's doing. it's probably noticing you deleting the default route and putting it back. What platform/version of NetworkManager is this? If it's pre-RHEL7 and a server then I would recommend just turning of NetworkManager completely, otherwise you may have to go into `nmcli` and see if there's something set that shouldn't be.

Comment: CentOS 7.1, NetworkManager 1.0.0-14

Comment: default is just a synonym for "0.0.0.0". You have two default routes for different networks (although the 2nd one is X'd out), so both could be valid. Are you sure that you want to delete one of them? What is your goal?

Answer (score -1):

Please try

```
grep -r "10.12.32.1" /etc
```

To search which file include such as `GATEWAY=10.12.32.1`
Then delete the `GATEWAY=10.12.32.1` in the file.

Restart your network service